# Which 13" MacBook Pro 2011 is right for me?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I'm completely new to Mac (OS X) and I want to buy a 13" Macbook Pro 2011. I'm not sure if the "2,7 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i7" is worth the +300€.
I want to order one of the two with a 128GB SSD for fast boots. I'm a developer (mainly web) so I need the book for programming and for the university later this year. I'm not going to install Windows or Linux on the machine. I need Mac OS X.

My questions:

1. Is there any advantage of a SSD in the Mac as long I don't plan gaming? Or do they boot up fast from some kind of sleep mode? I need a Notebook which starts really quick and does not loose battery when off (sleep mode etc.).
2. Is the i7 much better than the i5? I mean the only difference between the two books is only CPU and HDD.
3. Is 13" enough? I can't visit an Apple store since there aren't any in my region. My current notebook is a 15" one running Ubuntu and I think it shouldn't be much smaller. But the 15" Macbooks are too expensive for me and a 13" might be more portable. I'll connect the book to a larger screen @ home anyway.
4. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've ordered the cheapest 13" as my first mac.
I already have a 80 GB SSD which I will put in it immediately when it arrives. **An SSD is beneficial to about everything you can do on your mac because the hard disk is usually the performance bottleneck.**

Don't worry about the screen size and resolution if you'll hook it up to an external monitor anyway. I've played around with a 13" a lot this week and the screen size and resolution are fine for normal pc usage.

I would not pay extra for the upgraded CPU.
**Remember that the cheapest 13" has about the same cpu speed as the previous generation's 17" flagship!** (see benchmarks posted below)

So either way I would go with the cheapest version.
If you are unable/unwilling to open up your mac yourself I would take the SSD option. You can always get a nice little external HD with 1TB disk space for not much money, if you run out of SSD space.

Here are CPU benchmarks:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can only really answer question #3:

As a developer/photographer I think 13" is a good size for a laptop, as long as you are connecting it to an external monitor back at base. The 13" laptops are a lot more portable than the 15" ones, ideal for taking to uni!

Comment: I decided to take the cheapest 13". Going to buy it today or tomorrow. :)

Comment: I did the same thing and got the cheapest as my first mac and upgraded the ram to 8Gb.  It's actually faster than my Windows 7 desktop with an overclocked quad core.